# How can I delete a row from sqlite database using flask?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

The user enters input and it gets inserted to my database and li element but I want the row to be deleted once the user clicks on it or selects it and then click on a certain button

```
{% for i in results%}
<div class="container pt-3 pb-3 bg-primary my-4 bg-gradient-light">
    <ul>
        <li>{{i.name}} {{i.quantity}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
{% endfor%}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting rows from database with python flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25947251/deleting-rows-from-database-with-python-flask)

Comment: unfortunately no