# user_delete_connector() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'

Tags: python, flask, flask-apispec

I have these two methods, while in the `getall` connector it does not require any parameter from the URL so its working fine.
But when I'm trying the same for delete connector it is giving me error:

> user_delete_connector() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'

Help me out! To solve the specific problem

```
@app.route('/users/getall')
@auth.token_auth()
def user_getall_connector():
    return obj.user_getall_model()

#Delelte Request Method
@app.route('/users/delete/<id>', methods=['DELETE'])
@auth.token_auth()
def user_delete_connector(id):
    return obj.user_delete_model(id)
```

Comment: I think you need to define the route correctly like this: `@app.route('/users/delete/<int:id>', methods=['DELETE'])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete items from database using a Flask framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925024/how-to-delete-items-from-database-using-a-flask-framework)